# Unwrapping inner type from enum Rust multiple return type

Tags: rust, enums

I have a function that returns an enum (an enum is used due to multiple possible return types).

But a method on one of the enum's variant type.

```
myTypeObject.print_type() <- This function call doesn't work
```

The code is below:

```
fn main() {
    let myTypeObject = get_a_type(1);
    myTypeObject.print_type();
}

struct TypeOne {
    typename: String,
    typeid: u8,
}

struct TypeTwo {
    typename: String,
    typeid: u8,
}

trait TraitOneTwo {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self;
    fn print_type(self);
}

impl TraitOneTwo for TypeOne {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            typename: name,
            typeid: 1,
        }
    }
    fn print_type(self) {
        println!("My type is: {}", self.typename);
    }
}

impl TraitOneTwo for TypeTwo {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            typename: name,
            typeid: 2,
        }
    }
    fn print_type(self) {
        println!("My type is: {}", self.typename);
    }
}

enum Types {
    T1(TypeOne),
    T2(TypeTwo),
}

fn get_a_type(desired_type: u8) -> Types {
    if let 1 = desired_type {
        return Types::T1(TypeOne::new(String::from("Foo")));
    } else {
        return Types::T2(TypeTwo::new(String::from("Bar")));
    }
}
```

```
error[E0599]: no method named `print_type` found for enum `Types` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:3:18
   |
3  |     myTypeObject.print_type();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Types`
...
45 | enum Types {
   | ---------- method `print_type` not found for this
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
note: `TraitOneTwo` defines an item `print_type`, perhaps you need to implement it
  --> src/main.rs:16:1
   |
16 | trait TraitOneTwo {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have tried defining the type as below, which still throws an error:

```
fn main() {
    let myTypeObject: TypeOne = get_a_type(1).try_into().unwrap();
    myTypeObject.print_type();
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `TypeOne: From<Types>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:47
  |
2 |     let myTypeObject: TypeOne = get_a_type(1).try_into().unwrap();
  |                                               ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Types>` is not implemented for `TypeOne`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<TypeOne>` for `Types`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<Types>` for `TypeOne`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryInto<TypeOne>` for `Types`
```

How may I invoke the `print_type()` function?

Comment: Please post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, will be sure to post full error from `cargo check` next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`match`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html) on the enum like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    let myTypeObject = get_a_type(1);

    match myTypeObject {
        Types::T1(t1) => {
            t1.print_type()
        }
        Types::T2(t2) => {
            t2.print_type()
        }
    }
}
```

here is the [full example in a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6b94c4565205bc4f6656e03b710b1219).

Answer (score 1):

> But the function in that enum cannot be invoked.

The error seems entirely clear:

> no method named `print_type` found for enum `Types` in the current scope

The enum `Types` literally has no methods, how could you call that one on it?

The compiler even suggests one way to fix the issue:

> `TraitOneTwo` defines an item `print_type`, perhaps you need to implement it

Now that doesn't really work because your trait definition doesn't really make sense: why is `new` part of the trait? But if you move `new` to intrinsic impls and then implement your trait on the enum, it works fine, kind-of:

```rust
impl TraitOneTwo for Types {
    fn print_type(self) {
        match self {
            Self::T1(one) => one.print_type(),
            Self::T2(two) => two.print_type(),
        }
    }
}
```

It's not clear why you need *both* a trait and an enum though.

NB: you could also make `print_type` an intrinsic method of the enum, as well as do everything in it directly

```rust
impl Types {
    fn print_type(&self) {
        println!(
            "My type is: {}",
            match self {
                Self::T1(one) => &one.typename,
                Self::T2(two) => &two.typename,
            }
        );
    }
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dd097063943573b6d3b9c89643ba5a33

I don't really see the point of all the complexity, is this a java thing where you're supposed to use interfaces for everything?

Comment: Thank you so much for the full in-depth answer and detailed explanation. This really helps me learn Rust better.